# Checking a string contains no alpha characters

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to check that a string contains no alphabetical letters. Numbers, symbols (non-alphabetical letters) and spaces are allowed.

Comment: [Regex Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Comment: What did you try that didn't work? What programming language or tool are you using? Please include a tag for it, as the `regex` tag requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Unicode Character Properties](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop).

```
/^\P{L}*$/
```

will match only if there are only non letters from start of the string till the end.

`\p{L}` any kind of letter from any language **==>** `\P{L}` is the negation.

**Note**: Unicode character properties are not supported by all regex flavours.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution in JavaScript

```
alert(/^[^a-z]*$/i.test(myString));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one :

```
(?![a-zA-Z]).*
```

Explanation :

> - **(?!** -> Match if suffix is absent
> - **[a-zA-Z]** -> The absent suffix is compose from letters
> - **.*** -> Any character, any number of repetitions